# GamesClient not connecting. Error: "Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called."

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I am trying to use `GamesClient` to use the leaderboards of the Google Play Game Services.  Right now I have it so when the `importbutton` is clicked, the `GamesClient` is used to submit some scores.  As seen below I get an error saying `connect() and wait for onConnectd() to be called.`

What am I doing wrong?  I see in some tutorials something called a `PlusClient`.  Do I need that in some way?  I can provide more code if needed.

It seems that a lot of questions are on StackOverflow about this new Google Play Game Services but there is not a lot of answers out there.  Looks like people are still learning -- like myself.  :)

**LogCat**

```
06-12 00:40:40.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1685): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.
06-12 00:40:40.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.p.n(Unknown Source)
06-12 00:40:40.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.p.o(Unknown Source)
06-12 00:40:40.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.bj.a(Unknown Source)
06-12 00:40:40.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at com.google.android.gms.games.GamesClient.submitScore(Unknown Source)
06-12 00:40:40.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite.MainMenu$8.onClick(MainMenu.java:173)
06-12 00:40:40.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
06-12 00:40:40.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
06-12 00:40:40.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-12 00:40:40.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-12 00:40:40.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-12 00:40:40.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-12 00:40:40.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 00:40:40.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-12 00:40:40.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-12 00:40:40.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-12 00:40:40.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**MainMenu.java**

```
public class MainMenu extends BaseGameActivity {

    DatabaseHelper dh;
    GamesClient client;
    Context c;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);

        client = getGamesClient();
        client.connect();

        c = this;

        dh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        dh.openDB();

        importbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.importbutton);

        importbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                importScores();
            }
        });
    }

    public void importScores() {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(c);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.importlayout);
        dialog.setTitle(R.string.importtitle);

        TextView question = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.question);       
        Button save = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.save);
        Button scratch = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.scratch);

        question.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.importquestion));
        save.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.savebtn));
        scratch.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.scratchbtn));

        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                long highestJC = dh.getHighestJC();
                client.submitScore(c.getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboardjc), highestJC);          

                long highestTenC = dh.getHighestTenC();
                client.submitScore(c.getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboardtenc), highestTenC);

                long highestExodus = dh.getHighestExodus();
                client.submitScore(c.getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboardexodus), highestExodus);

                long highestGenesis = dh.getHighestGenesis();
                client.submitScore(c.getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboardgenesis), highestGenesis);

                long highestHolydays = dh.getHighestHolydays();
                client.submitScore(c.getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboardholydays), highestHolydays);

                long highestFacts = dh.getHighestFacts();
                client.submitScore(c.getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboardfacts), highestFacts);

                long highestActs = dh.getHighestActs();
                client.submitScore(c.getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboardacts), highestActs);

                long highestRandom = dh.getHighestRandom();
                client.submitScore(c.getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboardrandom), highestRandom);

                long highestAll = dh.getHighestAll();
                client.submitScore(c.getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboardallcats), highestAll);

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        scratch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dh.deleteAll();
                for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                    dh.insert(0, 0, "-");
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
                dh.closeDB();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to submit the scores before a connection is established.

Like the error says, you should wait for onConnected() and only then you should allow the score submission. Example: you should only show the button after it is connected

If you are extending BaseGameActivity, you should do something like this:

```
int isGooglePlayServiceAvilable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
if (isGooglePlayServiceAvilable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
} else {
    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isGooglePlayServiceAvilable, MainMenu.this, REQUEST_DIALOG).show();
}
```

And then, you should override these methods:

```
@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
   super.onSignInSucceeded();
   // allow to submit scores
}

@Override
public void onSignInFailed() {
    super.onSignInFailed();
    // do not allow to submit scores
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `BaseGameActivity`, don't call `GamesClient.connect()`. The advantage of using `BaseGameActivity` is that it handles all the connection boilerplate for you. All you have to do is override `onSignInSucceeded` and make your API calls from there. Don't make any games API calls before you get `onSignInSucceeded`.

Also, remember that when your activity gets an `onStop`, the games API will be disconnected. After that, when it subsequently gets an `onStart`, you would again wait for `onSignInSucceeded` before making any API calls.